# GreaseMonkey Help with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am new to GM and trying to write my first user script. I am trying to get a URL from a facebook comment I was trying to use this.

```
var e = Array.filter( document.getElementsByClassName('UIStoryAttachment_Title'), function(elem) {
    return elem.nodeName == 'A';
}
);
```

But each time I seem to open up a blank page any help on this would be great

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
Array.filter.call(document.getElementsByClassName('UIStoryAttachment_Title'), function(elem) {
  return elem.nodeName == 'A';
});
```

Comment: Thanks MatrixFrog No luck still does not trigger

Comment: The url that it seems to redirect me too each time is

chrome://browser/content/browser.xul

Comment: After you get that array, then what do you do? There's some other stuff that happens when you actually click it (onmousedown="...") but it looks like you can just use the href directly.